# change cell color of cell in excel if value is not changed from certain days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I change color the color of the Excel cells which value hasn't changed for a given number of days?

Can I do this with an Excel Formula?

Can anyone suggest formula for this.

Comment: Do you mean when the value hasn't changed in a number of days? Possibly give an example of what you'd like to happen. Also show the formula you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: Most likely you will need to save the date on the cell change, possibly on a hidden sheet, that will take vba in a worksheet_change event.  Then you can refer to these dates when using a Conditional Format.

Comment: I'm counting customer wise invoices in an excel sheet, so if the value of the cell is unchanged it means customer is not purchasing. So I simply want cell to be change the color so I can be alerted

Comment: You can't do this with an Excel formula¨. You need Excel-VBA

Comment: It's a little too broad a question to be answered here.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 2 steps

1. you will need to write a script ,that will set  a corresponding cell with last modified date , you can check script here

[how to record cell date change](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1895-excel-record-date-and-time-when-cell-changes.html)

2. next step to apply rule for coloring the cell 
   [coloring cell by rule](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/18/change-background-color-excel-based-on-cell-value/)